# Null Object pattern vs new object

Tags: java, design-patterns

I know that Null Object pattern lets us get rid of repetitive check of null. In my project there is a lot of code that looks like this (of course it's significantly simplified, just to show the idea):

```
public User getUserById(Long id) {
   ... // create db query
   return (User) query.getSingleResult();
}
```

and then we have

```
public String isUserAdmin(Long id){
   User user = getUserById(id);
   if(user != null) {
      if(user.isAdmin()) {
         return "success";
      } else {
         return "forbidden";
      }
   }
}
```

And now instead of checking if user is not null we can check inside getUserById method if result from DB is null and if so we can return NullUser object.

But my question is - what for do we need Null Object pattern (in this case NullUser object)? Can't we just return new User() instead?

Comment: If this were my project, I'd use Spring Data repositories and `Optional`.

Comment: Maybe you need to show more, but both returning NullUser or some kind of empty user seems like a weird thing to do. `Optional` or plain `null` are much more common.

Comment: getting an error when someone forgot to add a check is not the worst thing when it comes to stuff like access control (`user.isAdminUser`). At least you get a StackTrace and a clean crash. With NullUser, you may not figure out what is happening so easily (and empty User is even worse).

Comment: In our project we use `Optional` to represent possible nulls, and non-optionals must never be null. It also adds to the readability of the code without using annotations like `@Nullable`. A side effect is that they can often be handled nicely with lambdas, even though there are a few `isPresent()` lines which are effectively null checks.

Comment: The way I see it, NullObject gives you a convenient way to run code that only needs to run when some data that does not always have to be there is actually present without having to explicitly check for that. An incorrect user id that leads to a missing database entry is not like that. I want to default to hard errors unless I explicitly deal with that case.

Answer (score 1):

We can use;

- a `null` and check for `null` if you fail to check for it you get an error and stack trace.
- a NullUser can check for the null object assuming we won't forget to do that, or
- we can return a `new User()` each time and check for an empty user though this is likely to be more error prone and confusing than just using a NullUser.
- you can use `Optional<User>` where you still have to perform a check, but it has some handy helper methods.

BTW you should stick to a standard and if you find yourself writing code like this you have done something wrong.

```
Optional<User> u = ...
if (u != null && u.isPresent() && !u.get().isNull() && !u.get().isEmpty())
    // you have gone mad!
```

Comment: That you have `Optional` but still get no guarantee that both the `Optional` itself and the wrapped value cannot be `null` is a big shortcoming of Java's implementation (of course, they came too late to the party to do anything about it).

Comment: @Thilo @Peter `Optional` is since Java 1.8. Some projects use older version.

Comment: @user3056857 there are back ports and you could write your own ;)

Answer (score 1):

The NullObject programming pattern is used for when your code requires a valid object but you cannot deliver one, a null object basicly implents all methods and values of the original object and inherits it but does nothing if methods are called, this way your code will never error but if you give a null object in place of a normal object it wont error but also wont do anything

for example:

```
public class User {
    private string name;
    public string GetName() {
        return name;
    }
}

public class NullUser : User {
    public override string GetName() {
        return "";
    }
}
```

here you can pass a NullUser object instead of a user object to make sure nothing happens, but this programming pattern is only usefull in some cases

Comment: Very well put! This is an important point about NullObject pattern which is mostly not understood.

Comment: @wilcomega Yes, but if you pass user object also nothing happens (maybe getName() return null as it is not set). My question was - what is the advantage of passing null object over passing new object?

Comment: when you build the safety features into the object(s) themselfs, this would be useless, but if you have a class User and alot of classes that inherit from that class, you might not want to build in all the safety features that prevent it from crashing, insted you might just want to pass a NullUser to make life easier

Answer (score 0):

> Can't we just return new User() instead?

- A `null` user usually means a User could not be found.
- A `new User()` can be easily construed as some user was found.

So returning a new instance can be the right solution, but depends on your domain. For e.x. if you have a configuration, it may be perfectly alright to send a new instance instead of null.

As for **Null Object Pattern**:

As with all "design patterns", the correct answer is it depends. 
It depends on whether the problem the design pattern was designed to solve is your problem statement as well. From experience I can tell that if your intention is to just ignore "null" checks, then Null Object Pattern may cause more problems than it solves.